# A question in exercise 5.8 in hartshorne, chapter3.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

[image]

As in the picture, I have a question on the proof of part (b).I think I have found an effective divisor $D=\sum P_i$ on $\widetilde X$ with $L(D)\cong L$ and such that $f(P_i)$ is nonsingular point on X, how can I conclude there is an invertible sheaf $L_0$ on $X$ with $f^*L_0 \cong L $  from this? Can anyone give some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A picture to have in mind: if $X$ is a nodal cubic curve $y^2=x^3+x^2$, its normalization is just separating the two collapsed points at the origin (imagine that the singular point is an overlapping of two points).

Normalization only modifies the singular point. In particular, $L$ is the pullback of the line bundle corresponding to the image of the divisor. Normalization is finite surjective. For a finite surjective morphism, a line bundle at the target is ample iff its pullback is ample. (see Ex 5.7d).

Comment: Thanks,I don't have too much picture of normalization, thanks for your reply about this. I still wonder whether  there is any algebraic explanation about the proof?

Comment: What do you mean by saying that" line bundle correspond to the image of divisor"?  I mean X is singular, so there is no definition of weil devisor.

Comment: @Sunhf: Good point. The following description in terms of Cartier divisors is better: think of $D$ as a Cartier divisor on $\tilde X$ defined as $(U_1,\phi_1),(U_2,\phi_2)$ where $U_1$ contains $D$ and is away from the preimage of the singular part. Then we can descend the Cartier divisor to the bottom.

Comment: @Sunhf: An algebraic proof of the normalization is only modifying the singular part is because normalization commutes with localization. For a curve, a point is smooth iff the local ring is normal.